# Partial Specialization for an Integral Constant vs a Type

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

Is it possible to specialize a template based on whether a template argument is either a type or an integral constant? Here's an example that doesn't compile but which illustrates the intent:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>

// tag struct
struct DynamicSize {};

template<class T, class Size>
class Container;

template<class T>
class Container<T, DynamicSize>
{
public:
    Container() {
        std::puts("dynamic size");
    }
};

template<class T, int Size>
class Container<T, Size>
{
public:
    Container() {
        std::puts("static size");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Container<char, 20> a;
    Container<char, DynamicSize> b;
}
```

The Eigen library has support for matrices of fixed size or runtime determined size and does something similar to this. The implementation there is that the template argument is always an integral constant and the dynamic tag is just a constant equal to -1 but I'm curious if there's another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to have the `Container` template take a type parameter for the `Size`. Then it's the responsibility of the type to handle whether it's dynamic or static. I'm thinking any details specific to type of storage type could be confined to the `struct` types. Perhaps the following example is helpful.

#### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>

struct DynamicSize
{
    static const int size = -1;
};

template<int Size>
struct FixedSize
{
    static const int size = Size;
};

template<class T, class Size>
class Container
{
public:
    Container()
    {
        std::cout << Size::size << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Container<char, FixedSize<20>> a;
    Container<char, DynamicSize> b;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
20
-1
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/lp2jgJ)</kbd>

Comment: Classic traits approach.  Plus, with this approach, `Size` can default to a specific trait unless explicitly stated otherwise, eg: `template<class T, class Size = DynamicSize> class Container {...}; ... Container<char> b;`

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution by James is very nice!

However, if there is an actual need for ***partial specialization***, as requested originally in the question (e.g. for implementing a different behavior in the two different cases), riding on James answer I would propose:

```
#include <iostream>

struct DynamicSize {};

template<int Size>
struct FixedSize {};

template<class T, class Size>
class Container;

template<class T, int size>
class Container<T, FixedSize<size>> {
public:
    Container() { std::cout << "FixedSize: " << size << "\n"; }
};

template<class T>
class Container<T, DynamicSize> {
public:
    Container() { std::cout << "dynamic size\n"; }
};

// you can also do that    
template<class T>
class Container<T, FixedSize<0>> {
public:
    Container() { std::cout << "Special case of FixedSize 0\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Container<char, FixedSize<20>> a;
    Container<char, DynamicSize> b;
    Container<char, FixedSize<0>> c;
}
```

### Example Output

```
FixedSize: 20
dynamic size
Special case of FixedSize 0
```

---

### But why stop here?

If there is a need to ***specialize on the size itself*** (i.e. to create different implementation for different fixed size values, by predefined range selection), one can do:

```
enum class SIZE_RANGE {SMALL, MEDIUM = 10, BIG = 100};
constexpr bool operator<(int size, SIZE_RANGE s) {
    return size < (int)s;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FixedSize manages its own range selection here
template<int Size, 
         SIZE_RANGE SizeRange = (Size < SIZE_RANGE::MEDIUM? SIZE_RANGE::SMALL :
                                 Size < SIZE_RANGE::BIG?    SIZE_RANGE::MEDIUM :
                                                            SIZE_RANGE::BIG)>
struct FixedSize {};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Now we can specialize on the Container's size, according to its range:

```
template<class T, class Size>
class Container;

template<class T>
class Container<T, FixedSize<0>> {
public:
    Container() { std::cout << "Special case of FixedSize 0\n"; }
};

template<class T, int size>
class Container<T, FixedSize<size, SIZE_RANGE::SMALL>> {
public:
    Container() { std::cout << "Small FixedSize: " << size << "\n"; }
};

template<class T, int size>
class Container<T, FixedSize<size, SIZE_RANGE::MEDIUM>> {
public:
    Container() { std::cout << "Medium FixedSize: " << size << "\n"; }
};

template<class T, int size>
class Container<T, FixedSize<size, SIZE_RANGE::BIG>> {
public:
    Container() { std::cout << "Big FixedSize: " << size << "\n"; }
};

template<class T>
class Container<T, DynamicSize> {
public:
    Container() { std::cout << "dynamic size\n"; }
};
```

Which can be demonstrated by the following main:

```
int main() {
    Container<char, DynamicSize> a;
    Container<char, FixedSize<0>> b;
    Container<char, FixedSize<5>> c;
    Container<char, FixedSize<42>> d;
    Container<char, FixedSize<100>> e;
}
```

### Example Output

```
dynamic size
Special case of FixedSize 0
Small FixedSize: 5
Medium FixedSize: 42
Big FixedSize: 100
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Npj44d)</kbd>